# Creating table on php having error on sql syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

The program that I want to build is to create a table in **mysql** using **php**. The table name is the value entered in a textbox from a form of a previous page.

I am having a problem stating:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '2014( ID_Number INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID_Number), First_Name VARCH' at line 1'

```
CREATE TABLE $filename(
    ID_Number INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID_Number),
    First_Name VARCHAR(50),
    Middle_Name VARCHAR(50),
    Last_Name VARCHAR(50),
    Year INT,
    Course VARCHAR(50),
    Position VARCHAR(50),
    Party VARCHAR(50),
    Picture VARCHAR(50),
    vote INT,
)
```

Comment: String concatenation is wrong in the create table query.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the comma after the last column in your create statement

```
vote INT,
```

Answer (score 0):

> (Error creating table: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '**2014(** ID_Number INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID_Number), First_Name VARCH' at line 1')

Besides other possible errors (as suggested in other answers), above error message returned specifically because you were trying to create a table named **2014** which is not allowed.

> "Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits". [[MySql Manual : 9.2 Schema Object Names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html)]

You can escape digits only table name by using backticks :

```
CREATE TABLE `2014` 
....
```

Comment: This really helps. It's true that I entered 2014 from the textbox I used. It doesn't work. But when I entered tbl_ to '$sql = "CREATE TABLE tbl_$filename', it actually works. Thanks.

Comment: yup, escaping only necessary if the table name consists of digits only. Mix digits and `tbl_` string and you're good to go

Answer (score -1):

String concatenation is wrong. Try this -

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE $filename(".
    "ID_Number INT NOT NULL,".
    "PRIMARY KEY (ID_Number),".
    "First_Name VARCHAR(50),".
    "Middle_Name VARCHAR(50),".
    "Last_Name VARCHAR(50),".
    "Year INT,".
    "Course VARCHAR(50),".
    "Position VARCHAR(50),".
    "Party VARCHAR(50),".
    "Picture VARCHAR(50),".
    "vote INT".
    ")";
```